# generate same div thrice with data from database in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project in which I am generating a receipt for student,office and accounts.Currently I am displaying these three copies one at a time depending on the selection from radio button but I want these three receipts to appear on the same page,so that they can be printed on one A4 size sheet.I am attaching my aspx,cs code along with the screenshot of what i am using and also what i want.

aspx code

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblreceipt" runat="server" Visible="false" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblreceipt_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem>Student copy</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Office copy</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Accounts copy</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlreceipt" runat="server">
    <div id="divprint">
    <div id="divpnlreceipt" runat="server" visible="false">
    <table class="outertable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Image ID="imglogo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/scholar-logo.png" CssClass="logo"/>
                <asp:Label ID="lblreceiptcopy" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="receiptcopyheading"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="innertablereceipt">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"><span class="innerheading">ME-LUNCH RECEIPT</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Receipt No:<asp:Label ID="lblreceiptno" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Adm. No:<asp:Label ID="lbladmno" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col3">
                            Code No:<asp:Label ID="lblcodeno" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Date:<asp:Label ID="lbldate" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Name:<asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Class:<asp:Label ID="lblclass" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            For the month of:<asp:Label ID="lblmonth" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Father's Name:<asp:Label ID="lblfathername" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            School:<asp:Label ID="lblschool" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            Branch:<asp:Label ID="lblbranch" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Address:<asp:Label ID="lbladdress" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height:4px;">
                        <td colspan="4">................................................................................................................................................................................................</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="border-bottom:1px dotted black;">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            Particulars
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Amount
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr style="height:4px;">
                        <td colspan="4">................................................................................................................................................................................................</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="border-bottom:1px dotted black;height:40px">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            Me-Lunch Charges
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblamount" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr style="height:4px;">
                        <td colspan="4">................................................................................................................................................................................................</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"></td>
                        <td>
                            Total amount:<asp:Label ID="lbltotalamount" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Cash/cheque No:<asp:Label ID="lblpaymenttype" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            Bank Name:<asp:Label ID="lblbankname" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>(In words):</td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="txtunderline">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblamountwords" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblreceipt"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            *Cheque subject to realisation
                        </td>
                        <td>Cashier Signature</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
        </div>
</asp:Panel>
<div id="divstudent" runat="server" class="studentreceipt" visible="false"></div>
```

c# code

```
public void filldata()
{
    sql ="select s.admissionnumber,s.studentname,g.forename,g.relationshipcode,c.classname,concat(a.address,',',a.town,',',a.state,',',a.country) as address,e.amount "
        +"from tblstudent s left join tblguardian g on s.studentcode=g.studentcode "
        +"left join tblclass c on c.classcode=s.classcode "
        +"left join tblcontactaddress ca on ca.usercode=g.guardiancode "
        +"left join tbladdress a on ca.addressid=a.addressid "
        +"left join tblmiddaymeal_entry e on e.studentcode=s.studentcode "
        +"where s.studentcode='"+drpstudent.SelectedItem.Value+"' and c.classcode='"+drpclass.SelectedItem.Value+"'";
    ds = obj.openDataset(sql,Session["schoolcode"].ToString());
    lblfathername.Text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++)
    {
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["relationshipcode"].ToString()=="14")
        {
            lblfathername.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["forename"].ToString();
        }
    }
    string sqlrecepit = "SELECT * FROM tblmiddaymeal_receipt order by receiptno desc";
    DataSet dsreceipt = new DataSet();
    dsreceipt = obj.openDataset(sqlrecepit,Session["schoolcode"].ToString());
    string sqlschool = "select * from tblschool where schoolcode='"+Session["schoolcode"].ToString()+"'";
    DataSet dsSchool = new DataSet();
    dsSchool = obj.openDataset(sqlschool,Session["schoolcode"].ToString());
    if (dsreceipt.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        lblreceiptno.Text = "10000";
    }
    else
    {
        lblreceiptno.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(dsreceipt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["receiptno"]) + 1).ToString();
    }
    lblreceiptcopy.Text = "Student Copy";
    lbladmno.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["admissionnumber"].ToString();
    lblcodeno.Text = "";
    lbldate.Text = "<b>"+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")+"</b>";
    lblname.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["studentname"].ToString();
    lblclass.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["classname"].ToString();
    lblmonth.Text = drpmonth.SelectedItem.Text;
    lblschool.Text = dsSchool.Tables[0].Rows[0]["schoolname"].ToString();
    lblbranch.Text = "S.S.B";
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["amount"].ToString().Length == 0)
    {
        lblamount.Text = "";
        lbltotalamount.Text = "";
        lblamountwords.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        lblamount.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["amount"].ToString();
        lbltotalamount.Text = "<b>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["amount"].ToString() + "</b>";
        lblamountwords.Text = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + "<b>" + NumberToWords(Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["amount"])) + "&nbsp;only" + " </b>";
    }        
    lblpaymenttype.Text = drppayment.SelectedItem.Text;
    if(drppayment.SelectedIndex==2)
    {
        lblbankname.Text = txtbankname.Text;
    }
    string sqlcheck = "select * from tblmiddaymeal_receipt r where r.studentcode='"+drpstudent.SelectedItem.Value+"' and formonthof='"+drpmonth.SelectedItem.Text+"'";
    DataSet dscheck = new DataSet();
    dscheck = obj.openDataset(sqlcheck,Session["schoolcode"].ToString());
    if(dscheck.Tables[0].Rows.Count!=0)
    {
        string sqlinsert = "update tblmiddaymeal_receipt set date='" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "',forMonthOf='" + drpmonth.SelectedItem.Text + "', "
                         + "branch='" + lblbranch.Text + "',amount='" + lblamount.Text + "',paymenttype='" + lblpaymenttype.Text + "',bankname='" + lblbankname.Text + "' "
                         + "where receiptno='" + dscheck.Tables[0].Rows[0]["receiptno"].ToString() + "'";
        obj.executeQuery(sqlinsert, Session["schoolcode"].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
       string sqlinsert = "insert into tblmiddaymeal_receipt(receiptno,studentcode,date,forMonthOf,branch,amount,paymenttype,bankname) "
                    + "values('" + lblreceiptno.Text + "','" + drpstudent.SelectedItem.Value + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "','" + drpmonth.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + lblbranch.Text + "','" + lblamount.Text + "','" + lblpaymenttype.Text + "','" + lblbankname.Text + "')";
       obj.executeQuery(sqlinsert, Session["schoolcode"].ToString());
    }
}
public void generatereceipt()
{       
    divstudent.Controls.Add(pnlreceipt);      
    divpnlreceipt.Visible = true;
    divstudent.Visible = true;
    //divoffice.Visible = true;
    //divaccounts.Visible = true;
}
 protected void btnsubmit_OnClick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    btnprint.Visible = true;
    filldata();
    generatereceipt();
    rblreceipt.SelectedIndex = 0;
    rblreceipt.Visible = true;
}
```

screenshot of my page

[image]

output i want
[image]

Comment: That does not make sense to show three copies of the same thing in screen. You can make those things in the print command where you can add the header `student copy`,`office copy` , `account copy`

Comment: but my requirement is to show the same copy three times but with different titles-Student copy,Accounts copy and office copy

Comment: I cannot see your image. I dont know if others can. Please check.

Comment: ya its visible please check again and help me to solve my problem